# My HTML5 game pauses from time to time, how can I find out if it's caused by garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, html, garbage-collection

My HTML5 game pauses from time to time, how can I find out if it's a garbage collection problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for Chrome, you can check the Timeline tag in console and check the memory usage. If you see a big Zig-Zag pattern, that likely mean the GC is causing the stuttering.

Also this article goes in depth with how to optimize javascript game

http://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript